# Хранение Map и других подобных сущностей в стейте Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, map, state

Наткнулся сегодня на интересную вещь в редаксе:
Если в стейте редакса хранить Map, тогда мы можем изменять состояние стейта до того, как экшен вернет объект, при этом реакт будет использовать актуальное значение стейта при его вызове до того как перерисует компонент.
Вопрос в том, как использовать мапы и подобные вещи вместе с редаксом, чтоб не нарушать правило "изменить стейт можно лишь отправкой экшена" ? Я конечно могу вызывать изменение мапы внутри экшена, но тогда в любом случае, возврат объекта экшеном не имеет смысла, ведь мапа уже изменена!
Упрощенный пример:

```
//структура стейта в редаксе по умолчанию{ state: new Map(1, 100) }
function Component({TestReducer}) {
    return <button onClick={ ()=> {
      TestReducer.state.set(1, 1);
      console.log(TestReducer.state); // (1, 1) а не (1, 100)
} />
}
export.default connect.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, javascript и редакс позволяют вам здесь обмануть самого себя.

Редакс задумывался для работы с неизменяемыми объектами, и для корректной работы ожидает именно их.

Я стараюсь работать с неизменяемыми объектами.
Неизменяемость позволяет оптимизировать рендер.
Обеспечивает *атомарное* обновление состояния (действие или полностью произведено или полностью нет), что уменьшает количество ошибок.
Может быть реализован Undo/Redo и просмотр истори.
Код становится более предсказуемым.

Иногда полезно бывает сереализовать состояние в json и обратно. Несет ли Map в состоянии достаточную пользу?

Реакт -- библиотека (и это хорошо), она не заставляет использовать именно редакс. Есть встроенные в раект `useState`/`useContext` и множество альтернативных библиотек управления состоянием. https://stateofjs.com/

Comment: Получается, что в редаксе удобно хранить только примитивы, потому что любой объект может быть изменен без участия экшенов, так как в редаксе будет храниться только ссылка на этот объект?

Comment: А нужно ли вам именно менять объекты модели? Это одна из спорных вещей связанных с ООП.
Если объект может менять свое состояние, то множество таких объектов не изменяется атомарно (как в принципе ACID). Я бы сказал, что в одном из вариантов объект отвечает за то, _какое_ состояние у него будет. А за сам процесс изменения отвечает внешняя система (`obj.set(v)` vs `willObj = wasObj.with(v)`).

Comment: Я использую реакт с неизменяемыми объектами, но без редакса. Как относится редакс к неизменяем объектам произвольного класса -- точно не скажу.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то одним из решений этой задачи будет сделать функцию, которая будет возвращать измененный объект стейта, не изменяя сам стейт, а затем экшен будет отправлять в редьюсер этот измененный объект.
Но что если в стейте у меня лежит огромное количество информации?
Тогда такой способ окажется довольно дорогим, потому что в один момент времени придется хранить 2 стейта: текущий и измененный стейт

Comment: Да, но скорее всего это не будет заметно. Большинство объектов в стейте при этом будут те же (structural sharing).

Comment: Можно еще вариант: экшен будет отправлять в редьюсер _событие_изменения_; редьюсер вызовет объекту "obj.reduce(event)"; объект вернет свое новое состояние